# Is there a way to fix the 'j' in my equations solution?

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to make a script that solves the quadratic equation, but the answers have a 'j' in them.

I've tried using the regular math module but that gave me an error, 'cmath' is giving me this though.

Here's my code:

```
import math
import cmath
import time

print("Please enter A, B, and C values")

A = float(input("A: "))
B = float(input("B: "))
C = float(input("C: "))

X = B*-1 + cmath.sqrt(B**2 - 4*A*C)/(2*A)
Y = B*-1 - cmath.sqrt(B**2 - 4*A*C)/(2*A)

print(X, Y)
```

While it's giving me solutions to the quadratics, they're in an unreadable form making them useless to me. Is there a way to make it show the actual value?

The answers look like this:
(-4+1j) (-4-1j)
Is there some way to convert these or something?

Comment: Those are complex answers.

Comment: Note that you're fourmulæ are wrong - you need `2*A` rather than `2` on the bottom of the equation, and your parentheses are in the wrong place. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation

Comment: Paul R, I added the '*A' but I'm still getting the same answer.

Comment: the discriminant should read `cmath.sqrt(B**2 - 4*A*C)/(2*A)` (parentheses around `2*A`). and `B*-1` is probably more readable as `-B`.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I just changed it to that but I'm getting the same answers.

Comment: Quadratic equation returns two complex roots if b^2-4*a*c < 0.  You ought to know that.

Answer (score 5):

The 'c' in cmath is for 'complex.' The inputs you're giving don't have real-valued solutions to the quadratic, which is why you got an error when using the regular math module.

The 'j' is Python's representation of the complex number, sqrt(-1). In many fields (like my own, electrical engineering), a 'j' is used instead of 'i' (common in math) to avoid confusion with other things denoted by 'i' (like electrical current).

[Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number)

Comment: @wumbo52252 - I'm not sure how "put on hold as off-topic" works, but if this answers your question, please consider accepting it. Thanks!